# Use special iPad/iPhone autocomplete dictionary for certain text fields/text views?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, uikit

How does one use a special iPad/iPhone autocomplete dictionary for certain text fields?

So if in a certain text field someone starts typing in: "diarrrh" in a certain text field I want to suggest an autocomplete of diarrhea because it is one of the few known side effects of a drug.

For a given text field/area how can you supply a small limited iPad/iPhone autocomplete dictionary?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could implement the `UITextViewDelegate` method `textView:shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementText:`, inspect the last word a user has entered (basically go from the cursor position backwards to the next word separating character) and present suggestions with `UIMenuController`. If you additionally want to use the system's spell checker as a fallback for words that aren't in your dictionary, you could use an instance of `UITextChecker` (new in iOS 3.2).

If you have a `UITextField` instead of a `UITextView`, you have to replace "View" with "Field" in the delegate method's signature.